# Number of unpublished comments for each post

Tags: comments

How can I show the number of unpublished comments for each post in a theme?
I have searched, but I found nothing.

I also need to show published comments number for each post.

Comment: By WordPress theme, do you mean the theme options, else you can always see the comments published and unpublished(or waiting approval) in the dashboard

Comment: @MarutiMohanty i khow that. i want to show that for my visitors.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you're looking for the [`wp_count_comments()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_comments) function.

To retreive comment count statistics for the whole site, you can use:

```
$comments_count = wp_count_comments();
```

or for a given post ID:

```
$comments_count = wp_count_comments( 123 );
```

It will return an object with the following attributes:

```
$comments_count->moderated 
$comments_count->approved 
$comments_count->spam
$comments_count->trash 
$comments_count->total_comments
```

Check the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_comments) for more information and examples.